# Update list of time values from single column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is very hard to explain but basically I have a list of time values as follows in VARCHAR format:

[image]

I need to convert these so that each becomes the difference between 12:00:00 and the value in the field using just an UPDATE command?

How would you approach this situation in TSQL? Being as it is a VARCHAR and we have no date part I guess we cannot use any date functions?

Comment: Do you need the difference from `12:00:00 AM` or `12:00:00 PM`? Are the values in the table representative of a 12-hour or a 24-hour clock?

Comment: The first value should read 1:37:20 and the values in the table will only ever go up to 11:59:59 if that helps at all?

Comment: So you want (for the first value) `12:00:00 PM - 10:22:40 AM`? Are the rest of the values `AM` as well? Are you always subtracting from `12:00 PM` (aka noon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CONVERT(datetime,@varchar,14)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function to change between varchar and datetime without concern for the date portion.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), CONVERT(datetime,'12:00:00',14)-CONVERT(datetime,'9:19:4',14) ,14)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, I used the bit after the SELECT in my SET statement and it worked perfectly :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what has to be done, 
1) Convert the time column to the actual time data type
2) Using convert and simple subtract operation this can be achieved.

Here is the quick code (tested):

```
  select
     convert(time(0), 
        ((convert(datetime, '12:00:00')- convert(datetime, time))), 8) as TimeDiff
  from
    times
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle for this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d292/6)

Comment: The time data type is available in >=SQL2008

Answer (score 0):

Given the 12hr restriction you specified, the following should work.
You may need to adjust the Varchar length for your schema.

t.dt = your table and column name.

```
LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST('12:00:00' as time), CAST(t.dt as time))*-1, CAST('00:00:00' as time))as VARCHAR(20)),8) as newtime
```

So a potential update would look like:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.dt = LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST('12:00:00' as time), CAST(t.dt as time))*-1, CAST('00:00:00' as time))as VARCHAR(20)),8)
```